# After connectionDidFinishLoading other function don't run?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I am using NSUrlConnection to go to a .ashx file to do a MYSQL Statement and return the result. Then put it in a table.

In this particular one i am getting Categories, which is all working fine and getting the details it should but after the connectionDidFinishLoading function nothing else happens.

I put breakpoints in everywhere after it and in it but nothing happens it just ends before it goes to the table entering.

Below is my code and if you need any information i have missed out, please ask.

.h file

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface Category_TableView : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
    {
        sqlite3 *database;
    }
    @property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *Category_Array;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *Category_Table;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *type;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *Category;


    @property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableData *CatData;

    @end
```

.m file

```
            #import "Category_TableView.h"
            #import "Cateogry_Cell.h"
            #import "JobList_Table.h"
            #import "JobList_Cell.h"
            #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

            @interface Category_TableView ()

            @end

            @implementation Category_TableView

            - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
            {
                self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
                if (self) {
                    // Custom initialization


                }
                return self;
            }

            - (void)viewDidLoad
            {
                [super viewDidLoad];
                self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

                NSString *requestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://"URL"/forms/AppForms/app_latest.ashx"];
                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: requestURL]];
                NSURLConnection *con =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

                if(con)
                {
                    self.CatData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
                    self.Category_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                }
                else
                {
                    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to get connection. Please try again later" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
                }

            }
            - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
            {
                [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
                // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
            }
            - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
            {
                [self.CatData setLength:0];
            }

            - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
            {
                [self.CatData appendData:data];
            }
            - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
            {

                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to get connection. Please try again later"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];


            }
            - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
            {
                NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.CatData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSArray *jobs = [temp componentsSeparatedByString:@"||||"];
                NSMutableDictionary *temp_dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                NSArray *jobInfo = [[NSArray alloc] init];
                int count = 0;
                for(int i = 1; i < [jobs count]; i++)
                {
                    jobInfo = [[jobs objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"||"];
                    @try {

                        temp_dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                        [temp_dict setObject:[jobInfo objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"Category"];
                        [self.Category_Array addObject:temp_dict];
                        count++;
                    }
                    @catch (NSException *exception) {

                        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Exception Thrown" message:exception.reason delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
                    }
                }
            }


            //#pragma mark - Table view data source


            - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
            {

                // Return the number of sections.
                return 1;
            }

            - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
            {
                // Return the number of rows in the section.
                return [self.Category_Array count];
            }


            - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
                static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cateogry_Cell";
                Cateogry_Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
                // Configure the cell...


                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"In Table Function" message:@"Failed to try again later" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];

                if(cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[Cateogry_Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cateogry_Cell"];
                }

                NSDictionary *temp = [self.Category_Array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
                cell.Category_Cell_Label.text = [temp objectForKey:@"Category"];

                return cell;
            }

            -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
            {
                if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Cat_Cell_Push"])
                {
                    JobList_Table *DetailController = [segue destinationViewController];
                    NSIndexPath *MyIndexPath = [_Category_Table indexPathForSelectedRow];
                    int row = [MyIndexPath row];
                    DetailController.JobList_Array = @[_Category_Array[row]];


                }
            }

            @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is the `NSURLConnection` will work asynchronously. So when you get the data your tableview will be already populated with no data. So you need to reload your tableview, just add the folowing code as the last line of `connectionDidFinishLoading:`

```
[Category_Table reloadData];
```

Comment: I added this as the last line in that function and no change. It hits the [Self.Category_Table reloadData]; but thats it.

Comment: @pateman: did you set the datasource and delegate of your table view to self ?

Comment: AMAZING it worked... but could you just look at the table section as it isn't added to the table now!!

Comment: It works but it doesn't add anything to the Category_Cell_Label. i have checked and there is data in the array. I know i hooked it up properly as when i had static information it worked... The only other thing i can think is the style function within the if cell == nil isn't working

Comment: Did you adding the label to your cell via code ?  If yes then check you added the addsubview correctly and the frame is correct

Comment: no i use the storyboard and drag drop the outlet to the cell. i figured out why i had a nil cell and changed it but it still doesn't fill it

Comment: I get this error 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: Do you have any class like Cateogry_Cell or you are using xib for customizing the cell ?

Comment: I am using the Storyboard... all the cells coming in before the if cell == nil are nil? should they not?